# Is it possible to reset, and recreate firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate my firestore database to a new location, since google added a new Canadian region after we created our database in US-West.

The standard answer is you can't change the location of firestore after creating it. The only way
I've heard is possible is to create a completely new project. Obviously that has many down-sides.

However, I was wondering if its possible to reset and recreate firestore in the desired region within the original project as a work-around? That way I wouldn't need to create a new project.

The steps would be as follows:

1. Export firestore data to google cloud storage
2. Move exported data to a new storage bucket in the desired region (You can't run firestore import across regions)
3. Reset firestore
4. Recreate firestore in the desired region
5. Import the exported data into firestore

Comment: Nope, it is not possible to do this and you may need to migrate all the data to the new project. There is already a Feature Request for this https://issuetracker.google.com/165074506

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that might be the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it is not possible to change the region for a Firestore instance already created as mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#create) and you may need to migrate all the data to the new project.

Anyway there is already a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/165074506) so the location can be changed at any time in the same project